# Variables in Telnet

Tags: bash, telnet

I created a bash script which logs' into a server via telnet. Now I want to `cat $var >> /path/on/server/a.log.` $var get's specified earlier in the bash script before entering the telnet session. somehow the output `"sh: ---------------------------: not found`" is created in the telnet session.

I guess that happens because my file.log has multiple lines. the second line is "---------------".

here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$(cat /path/to/local/file.log)
sleep 1
sh << EOF | telnet 192.168.178.72
sleep 2
echo user
sleep 1
echo pass
sleep 5
# echo "$var" >> /path/on/server/file.log (Can't Test because saving the var is not working)
sleep 5
EOF
```

my final goal is to get file.log onto the server. the only way to connect is via telnet. the client doesn't support ssh or rsync or anything.

edit:
more information:

the script doesn'T HAVE to run on the client. I could run it on the server as well. i prefer running the script on the client tho.

Comment: You should consider using [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) or original [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend an approach such as this:

```
#!/bin/bash
(
echo "telnet 192.168.178.72"
sleep 2
echo user
sleep 1
echo pass
sleep 5
echo "cat >> /path/on/server/file.log"
sleep 5
cat /path/to/local/file.log
) | sh
```

Note that there is some potential for this to wind up executing the contents of `/path/to/local/file.log` on the remote server. I would strongly recommend that you consider the security implications of this and perhaps find some better way.

Comment: `: not found
           sh: Raspbian: not found`

Not working for me. I connect from my KathreinUfs910 to my Raspberry with raspbian. I thats why it shows something with raspbian i guess.

i know that this is not secure, but it is in my own network at home. i create the file.log and i know what will be in it.

Comment: This telnets into the remote host, then waits until that session is terminated before running `sleep 2` et al. I don't think that's what the OP is asking.

Comment: @chepner: Thanks, fixed.